# How to display the v-overlay element from the beginning when the page is accessed

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

I’m currently building an application using Nuxt v3.9.3 and vuetify 3.5.1.

I have an implementation based on the "ablosute" link below, which shows the overlay when the button is pressed.
https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/ja/components/overlays/#absolute

```
<template>
...
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row
      align="center"
      justify="center"
    >
      <v-card
        height="300"
        width="250"
      >
        <v-row justify="center">
          <v-btn
            color="success"
            class="mt-12"
            @click="overlay = !overlay"
          >
            Show Overlay
          </v-btn>
  
          <v-overlay
            :absolute="absolute"
            :value="overlay"
          >
            <v-btn
              color="success"
              @click="overlay = false"
            >
              Hide Overlay
            </v-btn>
          </v-overlay>
        </v-row>
      </v-card>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
...
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const overlay = ref(false)
</script>
<script>


export default {
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    overlay: true,
    absolute: true
  })
}
</script>
```

I don't know how to keep this and have the same overlay automatically appear when the page is accessed.
Can someone please tell me how to do this?

I thought that setting the `overlay` flag to true from the beginning would satisfy the condition, so I changed it, but it did not work as expected.

from

```
const overlay = ref(false)
```

to

```
const overlay = ref(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    overlay: true,
    zIndex: 0,
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-btn
        class="white--text"
        color="teal"
        @click="overlay = !overlay"
      >
        Show Overlay
      </v-btn>
  
      <v-overlay
        :z-index="zIndex"
        :value="overlay"
      >
        <v-btn
          class="white--text"
          color="teal"
          @click="overlay = false"
        >
          Hide Overlay
        </v-btn>
      </v-overlay>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very helpful.
But for some reason it was not working in my environment.
Also, when I press the button, the overlay used to appear, but now when I press it, nothing appears.

Comment: Is there a difference between vuetify version 2 or 3 series?

Comment: yes here is version 3 documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/overlays/